# Access Kotlin enum from Java

Tags: java, kotlin

I have an enum defined in a Fragment companion object:

```
enum class Channel {
    TAG_FRIENDS, CHALLENGE_INVITE, COMMITMENT_INVITE
}
```

Normaly I'll access it from another Kotlin class like that:

```
MyFragment.Companion.Channel.TAG_FRIENDS
```

How would I access it from a Java class? The `Channel` enum doesn't seem to be accessable...

Comment: Enums do not need to be part of companion object.

Comment: MyFragment.INSTANCE? In any case as suggested by Enzokie I would move the enum to its own separate class outside of fragment.

Comment: Yes, just moved it out of the companion object, and the enum is now accessable. Thanks for reminding me of something I should have thought of myself :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just in case anyone still need this:

```
 Channel.TAG_FRIENDS.getValue()
```

Comment: getValue() is not present in Java